# Smooth dragging effect with delay in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, drag, smoothing, motionevent

How can you achieve a smooth dragging effect in Android using Kotlin for example?
I should explain now what that means. It means when you move you already made the ACTION_DOWN action and move fast to another place the shape is not immediately under your finger - but appears there with a smooth delayed animation.
What I tried - I tried using animation using interpolator in the ACTION_MOVE but that still made the whole thing laggy.

Current code (achieves simple View dragging but it is not "smooth").

```
 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private val touchListen = OnTouchListener() { v, e ->
        val width: Int = v.width / 2
        val height: Int = v.height / 2
        val newX = e.rawX - width
        val newY = e.rawY - height
        when (e.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                v.x = newX
                v.y = newY
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                v.x = newX
                v.y = newY
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                v.x = newX
                v.y = newY
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

Comment: Which view do you want to achieve this delay scroll effect? RecyclerView right?

Comment: Actually ImageView.

Comment: I think you should go with [ViewDragHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/customview/widget/ViewDragHelper) instead of custom your own touch listener. This helper class has some interesting stuff to play, and it's already optimized by Google

Comment: I'm trying to implement ViewDragHelper but I get no logging into my call back. This is how I created the ViewDragHelper (gridLayout is the parent view of children). What else do i have to do to reach callback?


 `vdh = ViewDragHelper.create(gridLayout, dragHelperCallback) `